# Reading MATLAB data file (.mat) in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, matlab, scipy

I have an array of complex numbers in Matlab and I want to import that data in Python. I have tried all methods including Scipy module and h5py etc. Can anyone tell me any other possible way?
My Matlab version is 2017b. and python version is 2.7.

Comment: Why do you need to use another way?  `scipy.io.loadmat` does the job for you.  However, because you have a newer version of MATLAB, you may need the HDF5 Python library.  To avoid this, save your MATLAB MAT file using v7.2 or less.  Alternatively, if you just have an array of numbers, consider encoding it in JSON using `jsonencode` in MATLAB, then use the `json` library in Python to read the data in as a dictionary which you can convert to a NumPy array. It's the roundabout way of doing what you want, but it avoids using scipy all together.

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB, save your data with the `'-v7'` option:

```
myMat = complex(rand(4), rand(4));
save('myfile', 'myMat', '-v7')
```

In Python, load the `.mat` file with `scipy.io.loadmat`. The result is a Python dict:

```
>>> d = scipy.io.loadmat('myfile.mat')
>>> m = d['myMat']
>>> m[0,0]
'(0.421761282626275+0.27692298496088996j)'
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried this method and I'm getting the following error:
    byte_stream, file_opened = _open_file(file_name, appendmat)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual commands you are using and if possible an example of the data?

Comment: import scipy.io
d = scipy.io.loadmat('myfile.mat')

My python code has just these two lines written above.
and my error is:

byte_stream, file_opened = _open_file(file_name, appendmat)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: I am getting data from Matlab like this:

data=read_complex_binary('galileo_data');
save('myfile', 'data', '-v7');

Comment: Does it work OK with simple example data from MATLAB, as in my answer? If so then there's something different about your data that you need to investigate - can you show an example of it? If even the simple example doesn't work, there's something wrong with your Python/scipy installation, I guess. The code above works for me on MATLAB R2016b and Python 2.7.15/scipy 1.1.0.

Comment: its also not working with the simple data you mentioned. then may be I try to reinstall scipy.

Comment: You need to display to full `loadmat` error message (traceback).  I have loaded many `.mat` files with `loadmat`, and answered a number of questions.  I haven't seen this error message before, but it makes me suspect the problem is with Python opening the file.  It doesn't even get to the stage of reading and parsing the file's contents.